# How to choose item property to filter with typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

In my view I have:

```
 <input class="form-control" ng-model="cities"
                           ng-options="item.id as item.name + ', ' + item.region_name for item in cityList"
                           ng-change="cityChanged()"
                           bs-typeahead type="text"
                           matcher="name"
                           placeholder="Начните вводить..."
                           required>
```

cityList is like object:

```
0:
id: 152
name: "Dnepropetrovsk"
phone_code: "5322"
region_id: 16
region_name: "Dnepropetrovsk region"
1:
id: 152
name: "Adamovka"
phone_code: "5322"
region_id: 16
region_name: "Dnepropetrovsk region"
```

It's nearly 10000 objects.
In input it looks like "Dnepropetrovsk, Dnepropetrovsk region"
But when I type "Dnepropetrovsk", I see all cities in that region in asc, excluding Dnepropetrovsk, because the list of items is too large.
So, how can I filter only by property "name". Now it filters by all item properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter `| filter :{name:$viewValue}`  please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/SVevh1gXzwmDwb31fHMq?p=preview

```
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="cities"
                               ng-options="item.id as item.name + ', ' + item.region_name for item in cityList | filter :{name:$viewValue}"
                               ng-change="cityChanged()"
                               bs-typeahead type="text"
                               matcher="name"
                               placeholder="Начните вводить..."
                               required>
```